# How to get more Feed items?

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed

How would I get the next page or more results for a feed?

For example, when I go to [Security Now](http://leoville.tv/podcasts/sn.xml) feed page, there is no "next" link of any kind and the url parameter of "page=100" does nothing:

http://leoville.tv/podcasts/sn.xml

I get only 1 page of results of about 20 episodes. **However** my Google Reader can successfully retrieve episodes that are earlier than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed it is true that Google Reader caches the items and it is NOT possible to paginate on RSS2, RSS or Atom feeds (unless they have rel=next link, which none of them seem to have).

However, we can leverage the existing Google Reader infrastructure, with some work, to retrieve a list of, say 200 items!

Given the above podcast url we retrieve the latest 200 episodes by:

1. Using the ...google.ca/reader/atom/feed prefix instead of the usual view/feed as can be seen in your google reader.
2. Appending n=200 as the query parameter.

So we have:

```
http://www.google.ca/reader/atom/feed/http://leoville.tv/podcasts/sn.xml?hl=en&n=200
```

There is a very insightful reverse-engineered google-reader API project located at http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI

Comment: However, it seems I must log in to Google in order to use this URL. Is there any way to use it as anonymous?

Comment: @anticafe Sorry mate, I have no idea, as I abandoned this project long ago. If you figure it out, feel free to post an updated answer here!

Answer (score 3):

Google reader caches RSS entries.  You can't get any more from the actual feed if they don't allow for it.

Comment: Maybe some feeds have query parameters (e.g. ?num=100) that you can use.  Unfortunately, I doubt these parameters, if they exist, are published for you to easily find.

Comment: Nope, those parameters are not standardized. Thanks for the answer - now I understand...